# Fileupload Regular expression validation fails for certain file name in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, webforms

I am using fileupload control to upload file and at same time using regular expression for validating file name.

I want following file extension to be uploaded for `.doc, .docx, .pdf`  i use following 
command to valid file name

`ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\\].*(.doc|.DOC|.docx|.DOCX|.pdf|.PDF)$"`

```
 <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="ValidateF1" runat="server"  ErrorMessage="*" CssClass="row-validate"  ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="ValidateEx" runat="server"   ValidationExpression="[a-zA-Z\\].*(.doc|.DOC|.docx|.DOCX|.pdf|.PDF)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1" ValidationGroup="Careers" ErrorMessage="*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

It fails to validate following file name

`(K)+J01461+abced+high+En+(HR)(1).pdf` I am not sure why it fails while it works for `ABC_COMPANY_Privacy_v4.0_123456(5).pdf`

Am i using the wrong validation expression. I want to allow any file name with extension as mentioned above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this

```
ValidationExpression="^.*\.(doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)$"
```

Comment: If i only need to check for file extension then can i use `@"\.(pdf|doc|docx)$"` will it validate even file name which has multiple dots `.` for example `file.name.pdf` or `file.name+abcd(1).docx` or with spaces also

Answer (score 2):

It depends on entirely on what you consider a valid file name. Your current expression only captures file names with alphanumeric characters and the character `\\`.

From your two examples, it looks like you want to include `()+_`, as well as multiple dots, so you can fix your expression by just adding those into the character class.

```
ValidationExpression="[_.a-zA-Z()+\\]*\.(doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)$"
```

If you want to include the space character  as well, then just stick that in there too.

```
ValidationExpression="[_.a-zA-Z()+\\ ]*\.*(doc|DOC|docx|DOCX|pdf|PDF)$"
```

If you want to permit **all** possible characters before the extension, then using Vignesh's solution will certainly do it for you.

Comment: If i only need to check for file extension then can i use `@"\.(pdf|doc|docx)$"` will it validate even file name which has multiple dots `.` for example `file.name.pdf` or `file.name+abcd(1).docx` or with spaces also

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker, It depends on whether the Match function you are using is trying to match the entire string or only part of the string. If you try it and it works on one case, it should work in the general case also.